# UIStackView does not respect size of programmatically added buttons

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uistackview, cgsize

I have a `UIStackView` that includes either three or four custom `UIButton`s. All buttons are completely rounded, the left and right buttons are slightly bigger than the center one/two. Somehow, I can't get `UIStackView` to respect the bounds set by `DeckPageButton`.

Here's the function in my VC that renders the buttons:

```swift
    private func setupButtons() {
        guard let deck = self.deck else {
            log.error("Failed to load deck")
            return
        }
        
        let nFloat = CGFloat(deck.type.buttons.count)
        let rad = (deckButtonsStackView.bounds.size.width - (8.0 * (nFloat - 1.0))) / nFloat
        for type in deck.type.buttons {
            let button = DeckPageButton()
            button.setupView(type: type, size: CGSize(width: rad, height: rad))
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            deckButtonsStackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
        }
    }
```

And here's the `setupView` function:

```swift
func setupView(type: DeckPageButtonType, size: CGSize) {
        bounds.size = size.resized(multiplier: type.radiusCoefficient)
        layer.cornerRadius = size.height / 2
        layer.borderWidth = 5
        layer.borderColor = type.borderColor
    }
```

I tried different Alignment and Distribution options for the `deckButtonsStackView` and none of them respect the

1. aspect ratio of the Buttons - they are not square, hence also not circular
2. edge size - all buttons are the same size even though the inner ones set their `bounds`to a smaller scale

Here's the best outcome, which I've had with `FillEqually` (same code for three and four button options):

[image: StackView with three rounded buttons]

[image: StackView with four rounded buttons]

I've also tried setting the `frame` of the buttons instead of `bounds` and keeping everything else the same, this was the outcome:

[image: StackView with three rounded buttons]

[image: StackView with four rounded buttons]

Is `UIStackView` just a bad choice for my goal? If so, what would be a better approach?

Comment: You have set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`, which means you can't rely on manipulating the bounds or frame of the button. You must add constraints to set its size.

Comment: @Paulw11 I've tried removing that line as well as adding constraints to set `button.widthAnchor` equal to `button.heightAnchor` but I haven't had any luck with them either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use constraints to set the size of each button:

In `setUpView`, instead of `bounds.size = ...`

```
let size = size.resized(multiplier: type.radiusCoefficient)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width),
    heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height)
])
```

After that, setting the spacing to some reasonable value, alignment to "Center", and distribution to "Equal Centering" should give you a desired result.

Comment: This helped, thank you! Although the spacing is dynamic and not the number I assign, so the buttons fill the whole width. Do you also know how I could center all of them?

Comment: @cameloper That depends on what constraints the stack view has. You should add appropriate constraints to the stack view so that it is not wider than required. For example, have the stack view's centerX equal to its superview's centerX, as opposed to say, pinning the stack view's leading and trailing to its superview, which would cause the stack view to expand horizontally to fill its superview's width.

Answer (score -2):

Do not set ‘translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` for button or better use constraints instead of frame resize